# TCP/IP sending a string and receiving a string to a Robot controller using C#

Tags: c#, tcp, networkstream

I am trying to connect with a robot controller from PC using TCP/IP. The robot controller accepts only the ASCII string data from the PC (TCP Client). According to the Robot controller's command structure  I have to send a particular string and get ACK from it to get the access. 
I used the following code

```
try
{
    System.Net.IPAddress IPADD = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("192.168.255.2");
    int PortNo = 80;
    char[] ok = new char[33];
    byte[] Data = new byte[33];
    byte[] StartReq = new byte[21];
    String Start = "CONNECT Robot_access";


    // INITIALIZING TCP CLIENT
    TcpClient TCP = new TcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Connecting..........");
    TCP.Connect(IPADD, PortNo);
    Console.WriteLine("Connected");
    NetworkStream NS = TCP.GetStream();

    // START REQUEST

    StartReq = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Start);
    NS.Write(StartReq, 0, StartReq.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("start request send..........");


    // RECEIVE ACK FOR ROBOT ACCESS
    Int32 RespData = NS.Read(Data, 0, Data.Length);
    string ACK = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Data, 0, RespData);

    Console.WriteLine("The  ACK is {0} ", ACK);
    Console.WriteLine("ACK Received");


    Console.Read();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
    Console.Read();
}
```

I have aslo tried Streamwriter and Bufferstream to send and receive string couldn't succeed. My program runs through completely without any exception (except a 30s delay for Networkstream reading).

Comment: Just a guess, but you might need to send a newline. That is: `"string Start = "CONNECT Robot_access\r\n";` You also don't say what "receive string couldn't succeed" means. Do you mean that you never receive any data back from the robot? Does the robot do anything?

Comment: Thanks Jim....You are right the end of line and line feeding commands is the problem. Now I am able to communicate with the robot.. Thank you very much.